# Speedup Element-wise KL Divergence Computation for VAE in TF-Probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder, tensorflow-probability

I have a working implementation of a Variational Auto-Encoder. I want to compute the KL-divergence of each encoded sample w.r.t. a prior distribution: I know how to do that, but it's just slow!

**My question is:** *is possible to optimize the following code to make it run faster?* Actually it takes in the order of tens of minutes to compute the KL for each sample in the dataset, that's weird because a single training epoch takes less than 5 min.

Here is a minimal code example:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tfd = tfp.distributions
tfl = tfp.layers

def get_prior(latent_shape: tuple):
    latent_shape = (latent_shape[1], latent_shape[0], latent_shape[2])
    num_modes = latent_shape[1]

    shape = (num_modes, np.prod(latent_shape))
    logits = tf.random.normal(shape)
    logits = tf.Variable(tf.reshape(logits, shape=(num_modes,) + latent_shape))

    return tfd.RelaxedOneHotCategorical(temperature=1.0, logits=logits)

def get_kl_regularizer(prior: tfd.Distribution, num_samples=10):
    return tfl.KLDivergenceRegularizer(prior, use_exact_kl=False, weight=1.0,
                                       test_points_fn=lambda q: q.sample(num_samples),
                                       test_points_reduce_axis=(1, 2))
# model definition
class DummyVAE(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, image_shape: tuple, latent_size: int, name=None, **kwargs):
        self._base_model_initialized = True
        self.latent_shape = (5, 5, latent_size)

        self.prior = get_prior(latent_shape=self.latent_shape)
        self.kl_reg = get_kl_regularizer(prior=self.prior)

        self.encoder = self.get_encoder(input_shape=image_shape, **kwargs)
        # ...
        super().__init__(name=name)

    def get_encoder(self, input_shape: tuple, filters: list,
                    activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel=3) -> tf.keras.Model:
        from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten, Add, Conv2D, Reshape

        images = Input(shape=input_shape, name='image')
        x = images

        for num_filters in filters:
            x = Conv2D(filters=num_filters, kernel_size=kernel, activation=activation,
                       strides=2, padding='same')(x)

        # latent space
        logits = Conv2D(filters=self.latent_shape[-1], kernel_size=1, padding='same',
                        name='logits')(x)

        z = tfl.DistributionLambda(self.get_distribution, name='gumbel_softmax',
                                   activity_regularizer=self.kl_reg)([logits])

        return tf.keras.Model(inputs=images, outputs=z, name='Encoder')

    @staticmethod
    def get_distribution(params: list):
        logits = params
        return tfd.RelaxedOneHotCategorical(temperature=1.0, logits=logits)

# instantiate the model 
vae = DummyVAE(image_shape=(40, 40, 1), latent_size=8, filters=[32, 64, 128])

# random (image-like) data: the num. of samples does not matter
x_data = tf.random.normal((10_000, 40, 40, 1))
```

Now, what I'd like to improve is the following computation:

```py
@tf.function
def compute_kl(x: tf.Tensor):
    # computes the KL for a single sample x
    z = vae.encoder(x[tf.newaxis, ...])
    return vae.kl_reg(z)

@tf.function
def parallel_kl(batch: tf.Tensor):
    return tf.map_fn(fn=compute_kl, elems=batch, parallel_iterations=32)


ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_data)
ds = ds.batch(512, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
kl = []

for batch in ds:
    kl.append(parallel_kl(batch))
```

I usually run this code on GPU, with TensorFlow `2.8.0`